# How can i set back navigation button in my action bar?

Tags: android

I am using `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` for back navigation functionality but it is not working as properly as i need it and when i am using back button of my phone it works properly.
Is there any way to code on a button such that it work same as back navigation button of phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

you can try using this in Activity, too:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So your menu item "Home"'s click will be handled using that.

Comment: any error in logcat? and please debug if that code is being executed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but i always do this in my method when having the same back-button-like capability in another ActionBarActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and ofcourse:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You may/may not used this, its up to you :)